# How can I activate my SVG path code in html where as bottom right corner of sublime text already is html?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to style a SVG world map with CSS but it doesn't work. I think it is because my html code doesn't work for 2 svg paths. Sublime text recognizes HTML (bottom right corner) but the code is white.

I have copied/pasted this SVG code from a .svg file and the remaining svg paths are html activated.

Both my 2 unactivated paths start with `<path` and end with `/>`

On the first version of my svg code, all the code was white so I started to separate the paths so it has been activated only 2 remained unactivated.